# Footnote environment (memoir, article or amsart)

Tags: environments, footnotes

Is there a footnote environment?

```
Few cases are known%
\begin{footnote}
The first experiments date back to 1912, when\ldots

A second paragraph.  
\end{footnote}
```

### Context

I have a customized environment `mynote` where the authors of the manuscript can leave remarks (and the like); the notes are typeset in the body of the document, in a different color. Recently, one of the collaborators asked to move these to footnotes.

Ideally, I would like to change the environment definition from

```
\newenvironment{mynote}{%
  \par\color{purple}}{%
  \par}
```

to something in the lines of

```
\newenvironment{mynote}{%
  \marginpar{\footnotemark}% marginal mark for the note
  \footnotetext\begingroup}{%
  \endgroup\par}
```

But this seems to be a (very) wrong usage of `\begingroup`.

Here is an example of the current setup

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newenvironment{mynote}{%
  \par\noindent\color{purple}}{%
  \par}
\begin{document}

This experimental setup has evolved
greatly.

\begin{mynote}
The first experiments date back to 1912, when\ldots

A second paragraph.  
\end{mynote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: are multiple notes prepared separately and then gathered into a group?  if they are individually entered and marked, although there is not a footnote environment, `amsart` can accommodate multi-paragraph footnotes which have paragraph breaks marked by `\endgraf` rather than `\par` or a blank line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton nice to know! In this case, since the document is somewhat long, I would rather modify the environment definition than edit all occurences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this? Catching the content of the environment with `\BODY` and applying the `\footnotetext` to this?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{mynote}{%
    \marginpar{\footnotemark}% marginal mark for the note
    \footnotetext{{\color{purple}\BODY}}}[\par]
\begin{document}

This experimental setup has evolved
greatly.

\begin{mynote}
The first experiments date back to 1912, when\dots

A second paragraph.  
\end{mynote}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Tássio: Happy TeXing then!